# Transfer partially complete torrent from Windows to Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, transmission, bittorrent

I have started a torrent in Windows (Vuze) and it is at 18%, however I wish to continue the torrent in ubuntu on another computer.

Can I simply copy the so-far-completed downloaded files to ubuntu, then re-open the torrent in Ubuntu (Transmission) and set the download location to where I copied the files to? or is there something else I must do?

Comment: You'll also need to .torrent file. Either look for it wherever Vuze saves them or re-download.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would simply suggest to take the folder with the partially finished files and just move it to Ubuntu. then add the torrent to your program there.

remember to put it into the folder where your incomplete torrent files are stored. (it's the same for me).

the basic idea is to just copy everything, the files and the torrent.

Comment: thanks, worked for me. Kept the automatic downloading and automatic torrent load dir on windows partition so that torrents could be downloaded irrespective of which os I am running. Ubuntu does not mount the automatically mount the ntfs partitions, so anyone wants this to get this worked smoothly make sure that ntfs partitions/drive are mounted automatically while ubuntu/linux boots.

Answer (score 1):

In you case I would suggest to install Vuze/Azureus in Ubuntu copy the vuze or azureus folder from Windows located in \user\your_username\AppData\Roaming\ to you home folder in ubuntu and rename it to .azureus or .vuze. When I used Azureus, that's Vuze before it's got its new fancy UI, that worked pretty well.

The needed torrent files are stored in .azureus/torrents/.

Starting a torrent with incomplete data is quite simple, open the torrent file with the application, choose the directory where the incomplete data is stored and let the program (re)check which files need to be downloaded.